# Sphinx: list of functions in a module

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have some python modules containing mostly functions and a few classes.  Each one is documented using sphinx-autodoc in a separate rst.  What I want to do is to create a table or list of the module's contents at the top of each page, so for example, of mymodule.py is

```
def first():
    'First function'

def second():
    'Second function'
```

And mymodule.rst is

```
Page Contents
-------------

:create_page_contents_list:

Members
-------

.. automodule:: mymodule
    :members:
```

Then the output should look something like this:

```
Page Contents
-------------

first
second

Members
-------

first()
    First function

second()
    Second function
```

The question how to do `:create_page_contents_list:`.  I've have a look at using a TOC, but it seems that I would need to manually create an entry for each item.  I've also looked at autosummary, but I still need to list the members.  Any suggestions for automating this?  I'd rather avoid third-party extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something *like* the [autosummary extension](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autosummary.html).  The actual autosummary extension will not quite do what you want, though.

An example of how you might extend autosummary to auto-detect the contents of the module is given [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30783465/134391.)

Comment: Can you provide an example of its use in this case?

Comment: Currently that link seems to be broken. Something about a redirect loop.

Comment: How does this extension solve the problem? Using `autosummary` you still have to manually specify every single function/method/attribute in a list. A `:members:` option for modules, like `autodoc` has, is not available. The only solutions I found to automatically do this are based on javascript.
It really annoys me that most Python documentations don't have a concise table overview over all module members (glancing at you _matplotlib_).

Comment: Exactly, autosummary is not solving the problem. There is a related question here with some code-snippet for extending Sphinx: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569011/python-sphinx-autosummary-automated-listing-of-member-functions