# Python Sphinx Autosummary: Automated listing of member functions

Tags: python, python-sphinx

How can I tell the autosummary extension not to only list a single class but also all the class' members?

If I use:

```
.. autosummary::

    MyClass
```

In the resulting html file, there will only be one short summary like:

MyClass(var1, var2,....)    My Custom class to do fancy things...

What I actually want is something like:

MyClass(var1, var2,....)    My Custom class to do fancy things...

MyClass.doA(var1, var2, ...)   Does A very well

MyClass.doB(var1, var2, ...)   Does B even better

How do I have to configure the autosummary directive in order to get this (apart from tediously naming all functions myself in the autosummary directive)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can extend the Autosummary directive like below and call it like this:

```
.. autoclass:: your.fully.qualified.path.to.the.Class
   :members:
   :undoc-members:

    .. rubric:: Methods

    .. autoautosummary:: your.fully.qualified.path.to.the.Class
        :methods:

    .. rubric:: Attributes

    .. autoautosummary:: your.fully.qualified.path.to.the.Class
        :attributes:
```

Code (in conf.py):

```
from sphinx.ext.autosummary import Autosummary
from sphinx.ext.autosummary import get_documenter
from docutils.parsers.rst import directives
from sphinx.util.inspect import safe_getattr
import re

class AutoAutoSummary(Autosummary):

    option_spec = {
        'methods': directives.unchanged,
        'attributes': directives.unchanged
    }

    required_arguments = 1

    @staticmethod
    def get_members(obj, typ, include_public=None):
        if not include_public:
            include_public = []
        items = []
        for name in dir(obj):
            try:
                documenter = get_documenter(safe_getattr(obj, name), obj)
            except AttributeError:
                continue
            if documenter.objtype == typ:
                items.append(name)
        public = [x for x in items if x in include_public or not x.startswith('_')]
        return public, items

    def run(self):
        clazz = str(self.arguments[0])
        try:
            (module_name, class_name) = clazz.rsplit('.', 1)
            m = __import__(module_name, globals(), locals(), [class_name])
            c = getattr(m, class_name)
            if 'methods' in self.options:
                _, methods = self.get_members(c, 'method', ['__init__'])

                self.content = ["~%s.%s" % (clazz, method) for method in methods if not method.startswith('_')]
            if 'attributes' in self.options:
                _, attribs = self.get_members(c, 'attribute')
                self.content = ["~%s.%s" % (clazz, attrib) for attrib in attribs if not attrib.startswith('_')]
        finally:
            return super(AutoAutoSummary, self).run()

def setup(app):
    app.add_directive('autoautosummary', AutoAutoSummary)
```

Comment: This is awesome! Any idea how to get the methods & attributes from the page into the toctree? It seems that the autosummary :toctree: options break this?

Comment: Thanks! Never tried to apply the toctree option, but as far as I am aware you just have to extend the option_spec dictionary to include a `'toctree': directives.unchanged`.

Comment: This code goes into the `conf.py` (check, e.g., [here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html)). The `app` variable is the argument of the setup function mentioned in the documentation I linked. Here is an [example](https://github.com/markovmodel/PyEMMA/blob/devel/doc/source/conf.py#L285). Hope this was of use for you!

Comment: It works well! I had to make a change for py2 support, swap `clazz = self.arguments[0]` for `clazz = str(self.arguments[0])` or it'll fail with charset problems.

Answer (score 2):

You have to type out the class members as well

```
.. autosummary::

    MyClass
    MyClass.doA
    MyClass.doB
```

I like to split it up with titles or rubrics like

```
.. rubric:: Classes

.. autosummary::

    MyClass


.. rubric:: MyClass Members

.. autosummary::

    MyClass.doA
    MyClass.doB
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use [autoclass](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html#directive-automodule) provided by sphinx, You can approach that by replacing autosummary:

```
.. autoclass:: MyClass
   :members:
```

Comment: Ok, to clarify that, I already use the autoclass functionality. What I want is an overview table at the beginning of the html page which is followed by the autodocumentation. So that you see all class functions directly at once and the details below.

Comment: After check the source code of autosummary, it seems impossible to complete this now. https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/c411c343dd216f41d263b5f5a14ad14d3ff5dad7/sphinx/ext/autosummary/__init__.py?at=default#cl-198