# Automatic Python module documentation with Sphinx: add a table of content

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am using the `automodule` directive to document some Python module using Sphinx:

```
.. automodule:: mymodule.mysubmodule
    :members:
```

This works very well.

However, I would like to include a sort of "table of content" of all the members to be documented this way. For example if `mysubmodule` contains classes `A`, `B` and `C` I would these displayed as a list above the details (with links).

Comment: There is a directive called `autosummary` that does this, but it is not as "automatic" as `automodule`. You have to enumerate the members by hand. Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9770756/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/20569011/407651.

Comment: You might be interested in this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14621772/407651.

Comment: This answer links to a Sphinx extension that automates things even more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46500983/407651. I have not tested it, but it seems promising.