# How can I create a table of commands in a submodule?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a Python Package that is being documented with Sphinx. My module has most of the documentation in Python docstrings.

Right now, my resulting document looks like:

```
command_1()
  blah
  blah
  blah
  blah
  blah

command_2()
  blah
  blah
  blah
  blah
  blah
```

I'd also like to get an auto-created table that creates a quick table of commands in a module/submodule. Like:

```
command_1 blah
command_2 blah
```

Is there a way to do this automatically?

(As someone mentioned, there is an [autosummary extention](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autosummary.html). As far as I can tell, this doesn't do exactly what I want. The autosummary extension either creates document stubs, or summarizes documents. But you have to manually type in each command you want summarized. Or I just don't get how to use it.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sphinx: list of functions in a module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770756/sphinx-list-of-functions-in-a-module)

Comment: Looks like it. Although link to the answer in that question appears broken.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that, which is too bad because it sounds like exactly what you are looking for. You can probably find the module itself somewhere and I am guessing that it is documented with sphinx so you should be able to build the docs after downloading it.

Comment: Ok, found documentation on it elsewhere. I don't see that extension doing what I'm hoping for.